# Decentralized social media apps

Tags: dapps, decentralization

Facebook, Instagram and Onlyfans are all centralized social media platforms. You don't have full control over your content once shared, it becomes metaphysically subject to the company's rules and distribution so that they get a cut in commissions, whether by ads or fan purchases.

What are some good examples of decentralized apps, besides exchanges and are not financially-related,  that are purely for social media (photos, videos, other media) where many users meet to share/view one another's content?

Comment: I dont think you can do social media on the blockchain in a decentralized way because people will break laws and share stuff they don't have permission to or break other laws. You need an authority for that. So, not all type of applications are suitable for blockchain platforms. Napster is one example of such law break

Comment: if centralized social media can respond to complaints about unoriginal or obscene materials by punishing users who are breaking rules, wouldn't it be easy enough for decentralized platforms  to set up  a dedicated compliance team to do the same. what's stopping a DApp from having a "Report User" button?

Comment: yeah, but who is going to be responsible when the Report button is hit? In real world there are obligations and responsibilities ,

Answer (score 0):

- steemit.com
- all.me
- U°Community